# Best way to use defaults values from application.yaml in spring services

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have 3 services: `FierstService`, `SecondService` and `ThirdService`.

Each service to use 2 values from `apllication.yaml` - **firstValue** and **secondValue**.

I have this construction in each service:

```
@Value("${defaults.first}")
private String first;

@Value("${defaults.second}")
private String second;
```

Definition of these variables is smeared by the project. If I change:

```
defaults:
 second: foo
```

to

```
global:
 second: foo
```

In my `application.yaml` - I need to change it in all places.

I got the idea to create one service - `DefaultsService` and values from `yaml` to this service. And Inject this service to each service where I use it.

But I will have new excess dependence on these services.

Which way is better?

Comment: how often you rename these properties? I don't think we change properties very frequently. having said that, when properties are changed, you can update respective services as well. I don't see a case to create DefaultsService

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand what you're asking as it's not 100% clear but, if I do understand you correctly, you could use an alias like follows

```
global.second=${defaults.second}
```

Use global.second in your code and you can change your application file agnostic of your services thereafter to whatever you want.